# cannot import yaml on mac

Tags: python, import, module, pyyaml

The software I have requires yaml, based on the `import yaml` at the top. I installed pyyaml on the mac I am using and it still threw the import error. I tried to change the code in the program to `import pyyaml` but that still didn't help. Any idea what the module is called to import it? If you need more information just ask.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I used pip in the terminal

Comment: Are you able to install other python modules using pip and then import them?

Comment: Yes, just pyyaml seems to be giving problems

Comment: Are you sure the installation was successful?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For python2:
`sudo yum install python-yaml`

For python3:
`sudo yum install python3-yaml`

Comment: `yum` doesn't work on macos, it's **Red Hat** based for systems such as `CentOS`, `Red Hat Enterprise Linux`, `Fedora`, etc

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run `import yaml` if you installed `pyyaml`.
Did you try `pip install pyyaml`?

Comment: Yes, It's installed, but cannot find the module. `ImportError: No module named 'yaml'`